# asp.net core 3.1 not binding array of integers to action

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to bind an array of integers in my web page to a controller action. I've tried [FromQuery] and [FromBody] on the action and that didn't work. I've tried the "traditional: true" property on the ajax configuration. What am I missing?

```
$("#saveFavorites").on('click', function () {
    var values = $.map(favoritesDataTable.rows('.selected').data(), function (item) {
        return item[6]*1;
    });
    //console.log(ids);
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/Default/SaveFavoritesSelections',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(values)
    });

});
```

Here is the controller action I want to bind to:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SaveFavoritesSelections(int[] values)
```

Using the network tab in Chrome, I can see the post request and the payload contains the JSON object with the ID's correctly there. I can see in the browser that it is an array of numbers in JavaScript.

I think the problem is that asp.net is not binding them. Why not?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the target controller is not an `[ApiController]` then you'll have to use `[FromBody]` on your payload parameter.

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SaveFavoritesSelections([FromBody] int[] values)
```